# How to make an infix \if variant?

Tags: macros, conditionals, scoping

How does one make custom `\if` variants in core TeX?

I would like to write:

```
\ifshape{it} ... \else ... \fi
```

as in:

```
\textit{Italic? \ifshape{it}Yes\else No\fi}
```

Problem is, I get the error "Too many }'s" when I define `\ifshape` as

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ifshape}[1]{%
  \def\ifshape@test{#1}%
  \ifx\f@shape\ifshape@test%
}
\makeatother
```

Is the `\if...\else...\fi` construct actually lexically scoped?  I didn't think (La)TeX had lexical scoping.  I was expecting the above (definition plus invocation) to expand to:

```
\def\ifshape@test{it}\ifx\f@shape\ifshape@test Yes\else No\fi
```

Of course, it works fine if I say:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ifshapethenelse}[3]{%
  \def\ifshape@test{#1}%
  \ifx\f@shape\ifshape@test{#2}\else{#3}\fi%
}
\makeatother
```

but I'd like to write using infix notation rather than prefix notation, now that @DavidCarlisle has pointed out to me that `\ifthenelse` (from the package `ifthen`) is an infix monster and doesn't really do anything magical anyway.

Is there some combination of `\relax` and `\noexpand` that I need to insert somewhere to make this work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that the expansion of `\textit` begins with a conditional:

```
\ifmmode
  \nfss@text {\itshape #1}%
\else
  \hmode@bgroup\text@command{#1}\itshape\check@icl
  #1%
  \check@icr\expandafter\egroup
\fi
```

Let's see what happens when you put in place of `#1` your argument:

```
\ifmmode
  \nfss@text {\itshape Italic? \ifshape{it}Yes\else No\fi}%
\else
  \hmode@bgroup\text@command{Italic? \ifshape{it}Yes\else No\fi}\itshape\check@icl
  Italic? \ifshape{it}Yes\else No\fi
\check@icr\expandafter\egroup
\fi
```

Here's the problem: the `\else` and `\fi` of your argument match `\ifmmode`: you're not in math mode, so the "false" path is followed and then the stray closing brace is found. The macro `\ifshape` is *not* expanded, because it's in the "true" path.

The usual way to solve this problem is

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ifshape}[1]{%
  \def\f@shapetest{#1}%
  \ifx\f@shape\f@shapetest
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

and calling it as

```
\textit{Italic? \ifshape{it}{Yes}{No}}
```

In this case no `\else` or `\fi` will be seen until expanding `\ifshape` and they will properly refer to the `\ifx`.

An alternative way is to say

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\isshape[1]{%
  TT\fi
  \def\f@shapetest{#1}%
  \ifx\f@shape\f@shapetest}
\makeatother
```

that can be called as

```
\textit{Italic? \if\isshape{it}Yes\else No\fi}
```

A trick which is worthy a close look (it was devised by the grand Wizard himself).

What's this trick about? It's based on the fact that `\if` wants to find two unexpandable tokens after it. When `\if` is found in an expansion context, it expands `\isshape` and immediately finds `TT` that are equal, so TeX follows the "true" branch , which is empty, and the following `\fi` disappears. If one had used `TL`, instead, TeX would have followed the "false" branch, which is empty either!

Next comes, possibly after other tokens, the conditional which really concerns us, which is evaluated as usual.

In case the `\if\isshape` is found in a non-expansion context, for example in the "false" branch of another conditional, the `\else` and `\fi` that we intend to do the work of the inner conditional keep TeX happy as they are paired with the "bogus" `\if`.

The only important thing is that the two tokens are unexpandable, so `\relax\relax` or `\hfuzz\uchyph` would work as well.

Comment: That's diabolical cleverness if I've ever seen it! Cool, that works for me. I'm selecting this as the accepted answer because it suggests the conditional `\isshape` rather than a customized `\if` variant. Question: Why `TT`? The `TT` can be any pair of tokens. It took me a minute to realize that this has nothing to do with the teletype font but that it stood for "token token". If I use `\relax\relax` instead of `TT`, that works just as well, as does any unequal token pair. What would be the clearest token pair to use? (The most confusing might be `\fi\if`. :)

Comment: The important thing is that they are unexpandable, so `\fi\if` are not recommendable. But the merit goes to the grand Wizard, of course. You might use TL, for example.

Comment: I see you added some more stuff to your answer. Cool. And I just did a spit-take with my coffee when I read `\hfuzz\uchyph`. I'll go with `TT` if that's what the Grand Wizard himself used. It needs a comment anyway no matter what is used.

Answer (score 6):

If you're willing to change a little the syntax of your test to `\ifshape{it}\then Yes\else No\fi`, you can also use the following trick by Donald Arseneau (from the [\ifnum for real numbers](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/msg/f84f7fed32c32a17) thread on comp.text.tex) :

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\let\then\iffalse
\def\ifshape#1\then{%
  \def\ifshape@test{#1}%
  \ifx\f@shape\ifshape@test
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\textit{Italic? \ifshape{it}\then Yes\else No\fi}

\textbf{Italic? \ifshape{it}\then Yes\else No\fi}

\end{document}
```