# What is \iffalse for?

Tags: tex-core, conditionals

So this is something I've wondered about for a while. What use is a conditional that always evaluates to false? I guess it's a neat way to "hide code from LaTeX" but apart from that, is it ever useful?

Comment: For comments. And used as `\let\iffoo\iffalse`.

Comment: For (semi)infix notation of conditionals: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43373

Comment: It's great to comment out entire sections or beamer slides during editing.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Knuth's own answer to this is quite instructive: on p.211 of the TeXbook, he describes the evolution of the `\phantom` command.  At first, he used macros `\yes` and `\no` to decide whether or not vertical or horizontal dimensions were requested:

```
\def\yes{\if00}
\def\no{\if01}
```

Clearly, these have the same effect (in principle) as `\iftrue` and `\iffalse`.  However, he then learned that the way he defined `\if...` in his own programming language made this method infeasible:

```
\if...(\yes...\fi)...\else...\fi
```

I have inserted parentheses to show intent.  If the `\if...` returns "false", then the entire first branch is skipped *and not expanded*; alas, TeX does not know what I indicated with those parentheses, so it terminates the `\if` with the *first* `\fi`, because `\yes` is not an "`\if`" as far as it is concerned and it does not use it to match nestings.

Thus, `\iftrue` and `\iffalse` are syntactic hooks to support abstract decision-making.  Through them, the entire `\newif` mechanism (i.e. `\newif\ifsomethingstrange`, followed by `\somethingstrangetrue` when you decide that something strange has happened) is possible.  In fact, `\somethingstrangetrue` just defines `\ifsomethingstrange` to be `\iftrue`; it uses `\let`, so TeX *does* treat this "`\if`" as a legitimate conditional.

The tradition of tautologic in programming has a bit of a history: there are `true` and `false` commands in Unix as well, because sometimes you have to indicate success or failure in a particular way.  In that case, the OS expects a program to exit with a particular "return value", which these programs provide and nothing else.  So if you want to do some kind of complex test and then branch off the result using this mechanism, you signal to the mechanism using one of these commands how you considered the test to have concluded.

(The `man` pages for these commands are hilarious: `true` "does nothing, successfully", but poor `false` "does nothing, unsuccessfully".)

Comment: +1 for the great answer, and the delightful extract from the `man`.

Answer (score 23):

The following definitions are accepted by TeX:

```
\def\obrace{\iftrue{\else}\fi}
\def\cbrace{\iffalse{\else}\fi}
```

and, in expansion contexts, they can be used to make TeX see an opening and a closing argument delimiter; [I've used this idea](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43412/4427) to build continuous fractions using a syntax `\contfrac{1;2,3,4}` that expands to

```
1+\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{3+\cfrac{1}{4}}}
```

without the need for the user to ensure brace matching.

The main usage is, however, in the definition of new conditionals. When one says

```
\let\xyz\ify
```

(where `\ify` is any of the primitive conditionals), the control sequence `\xyz` is marked as being a conditional and so it participates in the nested conditionals matching. A command such as

```
\newif\ifxyz
```

actually defines the two commands `\xyztrue` and `\xyzfalse`, executing the latter. The two commands are defined as

```
\def\xyztrue{\let\ifxyz\iftrue}
\def\xyzfalse{\let\ifxyz\iffalse}
```

so that `\ifxyz` is always one of `\iftrue` or `\iffalse` and so can be nested in other conditional constructions.

Other programming styles don't use them; for example conditionals in LaTeX3 are of the form

```
\prefix_if_something:nTF {<condition>} {<true>} {<false>}
```

so that there's no explicit conditional nesting (but there's argument nesting).

Note that also `\let\myelse\else` and `\let\myfi\fi` mark the two control sequences `\myelse` and `\myfi` as being part of nesting conditionals matching; indeed both Plain TeX and LaTeX say `\let\repeat\fi` in order to be able to skip over `\loop` construction that happen to be in the "False" branch of another conditional.

Comment: Did you consider adding your continuous fraction code to the [brace tricks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9897) question?

Comment: @PhilippeGoutet Done.

Answer (score 11):

Every `\ifXXX` command that is not TeX primitive is always made equal to `\iftrue` or `\iffalse`. LaTeX contains plenty of these such as `\if@twocolumn` etc.

You usually don't use `\iffalse` itself, but some of these commands.

When you want to change `\ifXXX` to be true, you say `\let\ifXXX\iftrue`, which is exactly what `\XXXtrue` does. And similarly for false or course.

Answer (score 9):

It can be useful to make a complex macro do different things based on a conditional switch. In the following, the conditional is not so complex.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*\ConditionallyDo[1]{%
   #1Yes, I did it.\else No, I didn't.\fi%
}

\begin{document}
    \ConditionallyDo{\iffalse} % -> No I didn't.
    \ConditionallyDo{\iftrue}  % -> Yes I did it.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course, such a command cannot be inside a conditional. Probably, saying `\csname if#1\endcsname` and calling `\ConditionallyDo{true}` or `\ConditionallyDo{false}` would be better.

Answer (score 8):

I guess you know it but …

`\iffalse` is used for Meta-Comments in `.dtx` files.

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
% 
% Copyright (C) 2012 by Tobias Weh
%                       www.tobias-weh.de
%
% \fi
%
% \iffalse
%<*driver>
\ProvidesFile{twfonts.dtx}[2012/03/01 v1.0 Private XeTeX package]
%</driver>
%<class>\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2009/01/01]
%<class>\ProvidesPackage{twfonts}
%<class>   [2012/03/01 v1.0 Private XeTeX package]
%
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}

\begin{document}
  \DocInput{twfonts.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
% Documentation-Text
%
% \section{Implementation}
% A simple macro:
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand{\macro}{Hello World!}
%    \end{macrocode}
%
\endinput
```

`.dtx` is a file for literate programming. The two `\iffalse` macros hide the code from TeX and keep it visible for the user (i.e. reader of the source code).

Answer (score 8):

the usual answer for this kind of question is to see Victor Eijkhout's book, *TeX by Topic*
(`texdoc texbytopic` works on many systems).  it applies here too.